# Calculate accuracy assessment for MNDWI classified image (Overall accuracy, Kappa)

Tags: image-classification, normalized-difference-water-index, water, accuracy-assessment

I want to find a way to calculate the accuracy assessment for a classified image (classified by mndwi threshold). I already had the classified image and the reference water body in shapefile format attached below.

I calculated the MNDWI with a certain threshold for a cloudless image of Landsat 8 over my reservoir. I also have the reference data collected under shapefile format. So I want to do the confusion matrix to find the overall accuracy and kappa coefficient as I did try for my supervised classification before. However, in the supervised classification, I have training and testing points so basically, I understand how the code works but for my recent case I only have one big polygon (the reservoir water surface) so how can I do it?

How do I create a confusion matrix to find overall accuracy and Kappa coefficient?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So I did calculated the MNDWI with a certain threshold for a cloudiless image of Landsat 8 over my reservoir. I also have the reference data collected under shp format. So I want to do the confusion matrix to find the overall accuracy and kappa coefficient as I did try for my supervised classification before. However, in the supervised classification, I have training and testing points so basically, I understand how the code works but for my recent case I only have 1 big polygon (the reservoir water surface) so how can I do it? Thank you for your time!